# What is a good model for Product attributes

Tags: django, django-models

I'm making a cart for a online store. I have a model Product like

```
#Product
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    attribute = models.ManyToManyField('Attribute')
```

How can I make attributes models like size, colors with their keys like numbers or choices ('Red', 'Green',...) ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read up on `ManyToManyField`? 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

You'd need to define an `Attribute` model class to point to, then add the relationships via the field managers 'add' method.

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    attribute = models.ManyToManyField('Attribute')

product = Product.objects.create(title='foobar')
red_attribute = Attribute.objects.create(value='Red')
product.attribute.add(red_attribute)
```